# What is the unit of time in Unity?

Tags: unity, realtime

In Unity what is the unit that time follows ? (milliseconds, microseconds or seconds?)

Comment: I've down-voted this question because it does not show research effort. This information is extremely easy to find in the official documentation, as described in the answer below. Please get in the habit of checking the documentation and doing your own experiments to see if you can answer your own question before posting a question for others to answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can answer this question yourself with a quick trip to the documentation:

[Time.time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html)

> The time at the beginning of this frame (Read Only). This is the time **in seconds** since the start of the game.

[Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

> The completion time **in seconds** since the last frame (Read Only).
>
> This property provides the time between the current and previous frame.

etc.

Even without opening your browser, Intellisense shows you this information too:

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio intellisense tooltip for Time.time, quoting the documentation above.]

Note that these are in-game time values that are subject to pausing when the app is suspended, or scaling if you're setting [Time.timeScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) for things like slow-motion effects. You can also use [Time.unscaledTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledTime.html) / [Time.unscaledDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledDeltaTime.html) to get the real time elapsed while playing the game, ignoring scaling effects (useful for animating UI at the normal rate even during a slow-mo sequence, for example).